# Kernel space and user space layout in page table

Tags: memory-management, kernel, cpu, dynamic-memory-allocation, tlb

Assume that we have the CPU that has MMU, which works as follows:

- for memory management is used only paging
- every process has own page table
- virtual address of **every process** is split into user space and kernel
  space (like many CPUs with paging does)
- kernel space (concretely his virtual addresses) is shared between all
  processes (for example higher addresses)

Now imagine that, we are running several processes (of course in non-privileged mode). When we want to allocate additional memory for any process, it just apply following scenario in my opinion. We execute system call(s) and OS serves that (in privileged mode) by updating process page table or report some error code.

**My question:** But now, when we want to allocate some memory for kernel, we must update **all tables of all processes** in their kernel part addresses? As far as I know there isn't any kernel page table, which can theoretically solve that problem (but brings others), in CPUs that works similarly. So how to solve that situation, if is possible to occur?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: If your page table is stored as tree (like https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand-html006.png from https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html), there are small number of pointers to describe kernel space; you may even point these pointers to single pmd-subtree of kernel space. In this case you will do only one update of subtree for all processes.

Comment: @osgx Thank you for your answer, but you want to say me that when a process starts its page table is filled with pointers to page table that belongs to kernel space(multilevel pages)? Isn't it be better with following scenario? We have two registers for pointers to page tables - the first is for user space, the second is for kernel space. Both describe all virtual space, whereas every single page describe their part of address space. The key question in this construction is that every process has exactly the same kernel space with others processes, or there are some exceptions in kernel space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. I think, this link say it all:

[ARM Solution](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/Cihbfagh.html)

Very important to understand that is **Table 6.13. Translation table size**. In a short, the virtual space of every process is divided into kernel space and user space, of course. However, both spaces **have own table**. When process switch, kernel table pointer is constant, but user table pointer is changed. I hope, you understand that.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Great! There is another description about arm Linux - http://elinux.org/Tims_Notes_on_ARM_memory_allocation with same conclusion "*That is, when a context switch occurs, the kernel sets `TTBR0` to the `current->mm.pgd` for new process. `TTBR1` is global for the whole system, and represents the page tables for the kernel.*" and comment "*ARM uses a somewhat weird way of mapping the Linux page tables onto the ARM hardware tables.*". Still not sure about x86/x86_64 linux (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) and other popular *proprietary* OSes

Comment: There should be answer somewhere in https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/pdf/understand.pdf but the book is too long to find it easily. There is note at 86-87 page of the book: "4GiB/4GiB User/Kernel split" which says that there was patch to 2.4 (possibly enabled in 2.6) in 32-bit x86. After patch kernel and user will have only 16 MB of common address space; kernel will use own virtual space with switch on syscall/sysexit.

Comment: @osgx Thank you for your interest.